# Replacing a subquery in a PL/SQL trigger

Tags: sql, plsql, triggers

I have 2 tables. One called `Employee` and the other `Employee_jobs`. One of the fields in the `Employee` table is `job_name`. The `Employee_jobs` table contains 2 fields, `job_name`, and `Emp_count` (number of employees per job). What i'm trying to do is whenever i perform an operation on the `Employee` table then it would automatically adjust the `Employee_jobs` table. This basically means i have to add all the job names from the first table and count the amount of people per job into the second table. This is what i've come up with.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TR_JOB_UPDATE
    AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE
    ON EMPLOYEE
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        IF inserting THEN
            IF :NEW.JOB_NAME IN(Select JOB_NAME FROM EMPLOYEE_JOBS) THEN
                UPDATE EMPLOYEE_JOBS
                SET EMP_COUNT = EMP_COUNT + 1 WHERE JOB_NAME = :NEW.JOB_NAME;
            ELSE
                insert into EMPLOYEE_JOBS(JOB_NAME)
                VALUES(:NEW.JOB_NAME);
            END IF;
        ELSIF deleting THEN
            UPDATE EMPLOYEE_JOBS
            SET EMP_COUNT = EMP_COUNT - 1 WHERE JOB_NAME = :NEW.JOB_NAME;
        END IF;
    END;
/
```

I still have to do the update part but i want to get this to work first. I realized using a subquery within the logic block is not allowed but i am not sure how to replace that statement. I figured that i would need to check if the job is already present or not in the second table and take different actions based on that.

I am required to use a Trigger to make this possible.

Comment: Don't use trigger for this. Use View for calculated values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simplify the trigger.  First check if the value exists in the table.  Then do a single update:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TR_JOB_UPDATE
    AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE
    ON EMPLOYEE
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE_JOBS (JOB_NAME, EMP_COUNT)
        SELECT :NEW.JOB_NAME, 0
        FROM dual
        :NEW.JOB_NAME NOT IN (Select JOB_NAME FROM EMPLOYEE_JOBS) ;

    UPDATE EMPLOYEE_JOBS
        SET EMP_COUNT = EMP_COUNT +
                        (CASE WHEN inserting THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
                        (CASE WHEN deleting THEN -1 ELSE 0 END);
        WHERE JOB_NAME = :NEW.JOB_NAME;
    END IF;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `MERGE` statement as follows:

```
merge into EMPLOYEE_JOBS ej
using (select :NEW.JOB_NAME as new_job_name from dual) as j
   on (ej.JOB_NAME = j.new_job_name)
when matched then
     update set ej.emp_count = ej.emp_count + case when deleting then -1 else 1 end
when not matched then
     insert (job_name, emp_count) values (:NEW.JOB_NAME, 1)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this indeed seems like a way easier solution to what i'm trying to accomplish. It is my fault for not mentioning but i am required to use a Trigger to solve this as this is part of an assignment.